# What effect size to use for n<20 within-designs (with EEG data)?

Tags: repeated-measures, effect-size, small-sample

I am conducting a meta-analysis on language related EEG data. Participants listen to different types of stimuli and then the amplitudes of the elicited brain reactions are compared with a simple ANOVA.
Since most of the studies contain less than 20 participants, I opted for Hedges' g instead of Cohen's d as an effect size to avoid bias.
However, the formula demands the input of the sample sizes of the two groups being compared, which in my case would of course always be 0, since there are no two different sample sizes.

**My question therefore is:** Is there any other effect size metric I can use for within-designs with less than 20 participants?

Any help on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please can you describe the study design and all your variables in more detail..